Flexdashboard sidebar selectinput
In flexdashboard I have 2 pulldowns in the sidebar. When I choose an option in pulldown 1, then the options in pulldown 2 must match.
As an example: in my data I have a column Year and Month. Year 2023 has the Months Jan and feb. Year 2024 has the Month Jan. So when I select year 2024, the pulldown only must show Jan.
These are my codes in the sidebar:
selectInput(inputId = "Years", 
        label = "Year", 
        choices = unique(df$Year),
        selected = "")

selectInput(inputId = "Months", 
        label = "Month", 
        choices = sort(unique(df$Month)), 
        selected = "")

This is the code in the row with a chart:
dfInput <- reactive({
  df %>% filter(Year == input$Years, Month == input$Months)})
  
  renderPlotly({
  df1 <- dfInput()
p1  <-df1 %>%

The problem now is that when I choose Year 2024 it shows Jan and feb.
